# Python regex matching pair of quotes or "<>"

Tags: python, regex

I want to find and match `#include` directive in C programs and copy them.

So I want to create a regex, which matches both:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"
```

and the copy it for further processing.

Sure I could create two simple regex, but I'd like to have only one to match both. I can't
figure out how to make it.

So all I've got is `re.compile(r"\s*#\s*include\s*")`

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = """
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"
"""
import re
pattern = re.compile("#\s*include\s*(?:<.*?>|\".*?\")")
print pattern.findall(data)
```

**Output**

```
['#include <stdlib.h>', '#include "mylib.h"']
```

Comment: I guess dakov does not want to have `<>"` in the match ;)

Comment: @sphere mmmm I believe he wants to use the same expression to match both the lines.

Comment: Actually I want the whole line, even with the `#include` directive, that's why it's present in regex I've posted in the question :)

Comment: @dakov Yup. The RegEx in the answer will include the `#include` as well. :)

Comment: @EarlGrey Its there in the RegEx, please check now ;)

Comment: I've wanted to do it immediately, but forgot about it in these 8 minutes, already done :)

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern matches:

`#include [<"]\w+?\.h[>"]`

Comment: Wouldn't this pattern also match `#include "foo.h>`? Just wondering. I know this shouldn't appear in C programs.

Comment: Thats a fair point, but if that happens the c file wouldn't compile. (something I assumed it would)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, just because I rarely see any examples of the `(?(id/name)yes|no)` expression in use:

```
#\s*include\s*(?:(<)|("))\w+(\.\w+)?(?(1)>|")
```